# How to describe a customer's business

Tags: meaning, expression-choice

Which sentence is the most relevant for your point of view:

- A client has a retail business consisting of lots of shops
  distributed all over the world.
- A client has a retail business that includes lots of shops distributed all over the world.
- A client has a retail business with lots of shops distributed all over the world.

Any other options?

Answer (score 1):

To me each of your sentences describes a slightly different retail business, and I can't tell you what is more relevant.

> A client has a retail business consisting of lots of shops distributed all over the world.

The international business is *purely* a collection of shops.

> A client has a retail business that includes lots of shops distributed all over the world.

That retail business has, in addition to lots of shops, also one or more *other* important aspects (not necessarily related to the exploitation of those shops). Those shops might even only be a *minor* aspect of the business.

> A client has a retail business with lots of shops distributed all over the world.

Is in my opinion quite similar to your second sentence with a slight implication that the shops are a major part of the business.